# Glide loading same image given diferent urls in android recyclerview - Java

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have implemented glide very well but the problem is that it loads same image for different imageviews with different `urls` in `recyclerview`.

**The main question is** how can I load the required images and still keep local caching to save user data? Here is my code:

```
    Glide.with(context).load(objects.get(position)).apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter().error(R.drawable.logo).placeholder(R.drawable.logo).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
  @Override
  public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing something like this:

```
.into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
  @Override
  public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
});
```

Just simply put into the `into` function your `imageView`. If you still want to be notified whenever loading has been done you can use `listener` function. Your code should look like this:

```
Glide
   .with(context)
   .load(objects.get(position))
   .apply(new 
           RequestOptions()
                     .fitCenter()
                     .error(R.drawable.logo)
                     .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
          )
   .listener(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable 
                                   Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
   })
 .into(imageView);
```

Glide should handle the RecyclerView lifecycle by its own. The only thing that you need to do is to hide progress bar. You do not need to set the drawable into the ImageView by yourself.

**UPDATE:**
The mentioned approach is the best however it gives me some `lint` errors when using `SimpleTarget<?>()` inside `.listener()`, maybe be due to possible version difference and has forced me to use `RequestListener<Drawable>()` and it works:

```js
    Glide.with(holder.service_image.getContext()).load(imageArray.get(0)).apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter().error(R.drawable.logo).placeholder(R.drawable.logo).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return false;
      }
    }).into( holder.service_image);
```